# Conditional Merge of Observales

Tags: javascript, angular, xsd, rxjs, observable

I am requesting a file though http. That file contains information about other files which need to be included in the main file. In my case those are xsd files with imports but i think it can be anything.

You can view the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugtaka
I have included some some console output that shows that every request will be executed but in the end my observable doesnt emit any values.

There are 3 xsd files which are structured this way: main.xsd imports sub1.xsd and sub2.xsd, sub2.xsd imports sub1.xsd.
There should be a request for each file and sub1.xsd will be requested two times.

```
myObservable
.pipe(mergeMap((data) => {

    if (data.import !== undefined) {
      const requests: Observable<any>[] = [];
      if (data.import instanceof Array) {
        for (const xmlImport of data.import) {
          const localPath = `/assets/${xmlImport.path}`;
          requests.push(this.getXsdSchema(localPath));
        }
        const forked = combineLatest(requests);
        return forked;
      } else {
        const localPath = `/assets/${import.path}`;
        return this.getXsdSchema(localPath);
      }
    }
    const myEmpty = never();
    return myEmpty;
  }))
```

This is not the actual code from the demo. I tried to make it a little bit shorter and include only the part where the problem might be.
*myObservable* is the parsed xsd file that contains import statements which should be merged to the observable. If there is more than one import i try to combine those with *combineLatest* and merge them into the main observable using the *mergeMap* operator.
If there is only one i can skip the *combineLatest* part and return it directly and if there is none i tried to use *never* and *empty*.

In the end i would like to have a stream that contains all observables. I would like to use the reduce operator to combine them into a single object that contains the information of all Files.

If i replace *never()* in line 68 with somethink like *of("nothing")* the observable will emit values but the actual information is not included.

Comment: just replace never() with of({}) empty object or empty array?

Comment: @FanCheung i tried that already. In that case i will get all the empty Objects emitted but none of my actual values

Comment: so the source myObservable what does it emit  and will it complete? is a array emission with a fixed length that can be reduced ?

Comment: @FanCheung it is an http request. so i belive it will complete and it will emit an xml string which will bei mapped through an xml parser. Have a look at my demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugtaka. I dont understand what you mean with your second question.

Comment: I don't see any major issue with your code. If your XML doesn't have import then of course you will get a empty array from `of([]) ` (if you replace empty()), there will only be inner observable emitted if you have data.import

Comment: @FanCheung if you take a look at it in the stackblitz you can see that my xml does have those import statements. And i read them correctly and all is fine until i try to merge the observables together. I have been struggeling with this for almost two days now.

Comment: Could you make a demo with just RxJS operators? I don't know what `getXsdSchema` is and just what is inside of `mergeMap` looks fine.

Comment: Just realised you are doing recursive call. That will explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PierreDuc answer is pretty cool that it produced a parsed XML tree. Another approach from me which is similar to the original code except I used expand to do recursive call and at the end reduce the data to a flat array containing four items. Btw the xml2js.parseString needs to be wrapped in a Observable

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
import { Observable, forkJoin, empty, never, combineLatest, of, merge,zip ,concat} from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, expand,mergeMap, map, catchError, tap,last ,scan,reduce} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getXsdSchema('/assets/main.xsd').subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('data',data);
    });
  }


  public getXsdSchema(path: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(path, {
      responseType: 'text',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
      })
    })
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(data => {
        let rtrn: any;
        return new Observable(obs=>{

        xml2js.parseString(data, {
          explicitArray: false,
          tagNameProcessors: [function (name) {
            // replace ":" with "_" for all tag names to make sure that they can be accessed within javascript
            return name.replace(/:/g, '_');
          }]
        }, (err, xmlObject) => {
          if (err) {
            obs.error(err)
          } else {
            obs.next(xmlObject)
            obs.complete()
          }
        });

        })
      })
      ,expand((data)=>{
      if (data.xs_schema&&data.xs_schema.xs_import !== undefined) {
          const requests: Observable<any>[] = [];

          if (data.xs_schema.xs_import instanceof Array) {
            for (const xmlImport of data.xs_schema.xs_import) {
              const localPath = `/assets/${xmlImport.$.schemaLocation}`;
              requests.push(this.getXsdSchema(localPath));
              //return this.getXsdSchema(localPath)
            }
            const forked = merge(...requests);
            return forked;
          } else {
            const localPath = `/assets/${data.xs_schema.xs_import.$.schemaLocation}`;
            return this.getXsdSchema(localPath);
          }
        }
        return empty()
      })
      ,reduce((acc,curr)=>acc.concat(curr),[])

      )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the path is `xs_schema.xs_schema.xs_import`. This can be avoided by using the `explicitRoot: false` option. I've forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqttjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), basically what it does is replace the data of the files inside the `xs_import` property:

```
public getXsdSchema(path: string): Observable<any> {
  //console.log(path);
  return this.http.get(path, {
    responseType: 'text',
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    })
  })
    .pipe(concatMap(data => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        xml2js.parseString(data, {
          explicitArray: false,
          explicitRoot: false,
          tagNameProcessors: [function (name) {
            // replace ":" with "_" for all tag names to make sure that they can be accessed within javascript
            return name.replace(/:/g, '_');
          }]
        }, (err, xmlObject) => {
          err ? reject(err) : resolve(xmlObject);
        });
      });
    }),
    concatMap((data: any) => {
      if (data.xs_import) {
        if (!Array.isArray(data.xs_import)) {
          data.xs_import = data.xs_import ? [data.xs_import] : [];
        }

        return zip(...data.xs_import.map((xmlImport) => 
          this.getXsdSchema(`/assets/${xmlImport.$.schemaLocation}`)
        )).pipe(
          map((imports) => {
            data.xs_import = imports;
            return data;
          })
        );

      } else {
        return of(data);
      }
    }))
}
```

FYI: you can combine operators by separating them with a comma inside the pipe call.

This results in:

```
$: Object
xs_element: Object
xs_import: Array[2]
  0: Object
    $: Object
    xs_simpleType: Object
  1: Object
    $: Object
    xs_complexType: Object
    xs_import: Array[1]
      0: Object
        $: Object
        xs_simpleType: Object
```